# Verificar se a string contém somente números

Tags: java

Como posso verificar se uma string contém apenas números?

Por exemplo, não pode ter `* / = e` etc... somente números.

Porque eu preciso converter uma string em int e se digitarem letras, simbolos irá gerar um erro.

Comment: Tente melhorar mais sua pergunta, colocando um exemplo que pode e o que não pode e porque!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma das formas de saber se a string contém somente números, é usando uma expressão regular

```
"1239417".matches("[0-9]+");   // true
"12312a".matches("[0-9]+");    // false
"12312+".matches("[0-9]+");    // false
```

Na expressão regular `[0-9]+`

- `[` e `]`: delimita um set de caracteres
- `0-9`: o set de caracteres, qualquer um entre 0 e 9
- `+`: da expressão definida, deve corresponder com 1 ou mais grupos

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma é tentar a conversão para inteiro:

```
    String input = "123s";
    try {
        Integer.valueOf(input);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Número inválido");
    }
```

Comment: Eu só diria para capturar a exceção específica.